# Toggling an Outlook FormRegion

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I'm looking to create a FormRegion on a NewMailMessage item in Outlook 2010 whose visibility is toggled based on a control in a Ribbon.  I've been banging my head for about 2 hours and haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to toggle a Form Region - you need to build a [Custom Task Pane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) integrated with [Ribbon extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386097.aspx). There is no way to toggle a [Form Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942843%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) once it has been opened unless the user initiates it via the form region expand/collapse action. Custom Task Panes are what you are looking for.

Comment: jeez--i really hate using the designer to get my ribbons correct.